# LARAVEL Reconocimiento de auth multitabla para acceder a Home

Tags: php, laravel, login

**Detalle**
He añadido una nueva tabla de Admin para logeo personalizado a diferentes secciones, todo me funciona perfecto del inicio de sesión  tal como lo tengo ahora, y editando el `config/auth` todo bien hasta ahí. Mi problema es que no puedo llamar a la vista `home.blade.php` una vez iniciado sesión, por la tanto me toca llamar a otra vista, mi controlador actual:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $guard = 'experto';

    function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth:admin', ['only' => ['secret']]);
    }

    public function authenticated(){
        return redirect('admin/area'); // <--- Me funciona así.
        return redirect('home'); // <--- NO me funciona así.

    }

    public function secret(){
        return 'Hola '.auth('admin')->user()->nombre.' '.auth('admin')->user()->email;
    }

}
```

Error al intentar redireccionar a `home`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe que puedo hacer para que home identifique que se ha logueado ya sea con el `guest` *Users o Admin*

**route:list**

```
+--------+----------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                     | Name          | Action                                                          | Middleware         |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                       | home          | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                       | web,auth           |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/area              |               | App\Http\Controllers\EmbajadorController@secret                 | web,auth:embajador |
|        | POST     | admin/login             |               | App\Http\Controllers\EmbajadorController@login                  | web                |
|        | POST     | login                   |               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                  | web,guest          |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                   |               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm          | web,guest          |
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                  |               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout                 | web                |
|        | POST     | password/email          |               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail | web,guest          |
|        | POST     | password/reset          |               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset              | web,guest          |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token?} |               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm      | web,guest          |
|        | POST     | register                |               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register               | web,guest          |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                |               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm   | web,guest          |
|        | GET|HEAD | test                    |               | Closure                                                         | web                |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Puedes pasar el resultado de este comando php artisan route:list

Comment: @SOSkr listo, he agregado el route list.

Comment: intenta redirect()->route('home'); o return redirect('/');

Comment: que versión de Laravel estas usando? para darte la respuesta mas apropiadamente

Comment: la versión es 5.2

Comment: ya te deje la respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que estas usando Laravel 5+ la forma correcta de usar redirect a una ruta con nombre es la siguiente

```
redirect()->route('home');
```

Comment: Si lo hago de esa forma me envía directamente a `http://localhost:8000/admin/login` que vendría siendo donde hace la autentificación, ni siquiera retorna la vista. :/

Comment: Eso es por que la tienes restringida con el midleware de Auth así que te pide autenticación, pregunto el midleware de auth es el mismo de admin?

Comment: Mi sugerencia es que no crees una tabla aparte para los admnistradores, crea una tabla de roles y para las rutas de administrador agregas una validación de que tenga el rol administrador.

Comment: Como indica @SOSkr no tienes ninguna ruta `/home` lo que tienes es la ruta `/` con el alias `home` , por lo que debes hacer como te indica: `redirect()->route('home');` o `return redirect('/');`

Comment: Creo que todo viene en el `midleware` debido a que el controlador de home por defecto lo verifica `$this->middleware('auth');` donde puedo personalizarlo?

Comment: Otra opción seria al `Auth::` agregar los datos que genera en mi funcion `secret` ¿se puede?

Comment: es mejor que crees uno nuevo o simplemente quitale ese middleware a home, en caso de que no sea necesario que este autenticado